# Is it possible to divide summations across both sides of an equation?

Tags: summation

For example, when $\sum$ goes from $i=0$ to $k$ on both sides:
$$\sum_{i=0}^k n_i b^i \equiv \sum_{i=0}^k n_i \pmod{b-1}$$

Is it possible to divide out the n<sub>i</sub> on both sides? If not, are there any other ways to simplify this equation that I may be missing?

Comment: It's hard to decipher what you meant. Write mathematics in this site with LaTeX, please.

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct to divide. If it is useful, you might rewrite as 
$$\sum_{i=0}^kn_i(b^i-1)\equiv 0\pmod{b-1}.$$

It is useful, for example, if you want to **prove** that your relationship holds for all choices of the $n_i$. That is because one can show that $b^i-1\equiv 0\pmod{b-1}$.

That's just a fancy way of saying that $b-1$ divides $b^n-1$.  The result is not hard to see, since we have
$$b^n-1=(b-1)(b^{n-1}+b^{n-2}+\cdots+b+1).$$

**Remark:** It is quite a bit easier to work directly with **congruences**. Note that $b\equiv 1\pmod{b-1}$. So $b^i\equiv 1\pmod{b-1}$ for all $i$. It follows immediately that
$$\sum_0^k n_ib^i\equiv \sum_0^k (n_i)(1)=\sum_0^k n_i.$$

That will give you a generalization of the old-fashioned "casting out nines" process to a base-$b$ system.

Answer (score 0):

We have $b \equiv 1$ modulo $b - 1$ so for any $i$ we have $b^i \equiv 1$ modulo $b - 1$, but this **doesn't** come from "dividing" the summation, remember that
$$\sum x_iy_i$$
means
$$x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + x_3y_3 + \cdots$$
so you can't divide out $\sum x_i$.

Anyway, $b^i \equiv 1$ modulo $b - 1$ is trivially true and you aren't going to get any information about the $n_i$ from it.  The only simplification you could make is to combine the summations:
$$\sum_{i = 0}^kn_i(b^i - 1) \equiv 0 \pmod{b - 1}$$
but again $b^i - 1 \equiv 0$ modulo $b - 1$ so this won't give you any information about the $n_i$.